# Swift not changing variable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am currently modifying this tutorial from https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-php-mysql-tutorial/ . The purpose of the program is to close a ViewController if the correct message is recieved and to display a UIAltertAction if an invalid message is recieved. Could there be something that i am missing that "notChangingVariable" is never changing?

```
    ...IBACTION...
    var notChangingVariable: Int

    notChangingVariable = 0
    ...othervariablesdeclared...
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in
        if(error != nil){
            return;
        }

        //parsing the response
        do{
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            //parsing the json
            if let parseJSON = myJSON{
                var msg : String!
                //getting the json response
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                if(msg == "SameTeam"){
                    print(msg)
                    notChangingVariable  = 1
                    print(notChangingVariable)
                }
            }
        }catch{
            print("error32 is \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print(notChangingVariable) //IS 0

    ...FURTHER USE notChangingVariable...
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered a lot already. Please have a look at this example - if you don't like this one, there's plenty existing others.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
notChangingVariable  = 1
```

is inside a completion handler.
It will be called, and the var will be changed, but it will happen after the line

```
print(notChangingVariable) //IS 0
```

Comment: So at what point/how can i use it after it officially has been changed?

Comment: You can call a function from the completion handler in which you can use your var

Comment: Ok i have done that but now another issue arises where i get a "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" when i try to miss a view controller in the closure or Show a action controller

Answer (score 0):

you are printing it before this part execution:

```
do{//converting resonse to NSDictionary
            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            //parsing the json
            if let parseJSON = myJSON{
                var msg : String!
                //getting the json response
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                if(msg == "SameTeam"){
                    print(msg)
                    notChangingVariable  = 1
                    print(notChangingVariable)
                }
            }
        }
```

it will never change in this scenario.